# CefSharp LoadUrl when browser not initialized

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium, cefsharp

I came across other CefSharp related thread where it was stated that LoadUrl() will fail if ChromiumWebBrowser wasn't yet initialized. However in my code, I call LoadUrl immediately after having created ChromiumWebBrowser instance and it works perfectly fine.

```
var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
control.Content = browser;
browser.LoadUrl(url);
```

Please note I instantiate the class without address parameter.

I was thinking that maybe I should handle IsBrowserInitializedChanged event and LoadUrl there instead, but this seems to be working. What is the right approach?

Comment: Improvements were made in version 95, this is now supported. If it is working as expected then keep your code as is. For reference https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/b82fa05291e03ee22f69ba1babd0e44eef3021c7#diff-b27c014d78a0c17c1c8fe22fc001dcc3f8c02617541b121258af40ada3f928e4

Comment: @amaitland thanks! And I see LoadUrl calls Load so it applies to both. By the way, is there any difference known to you in browser behavior depending on whether you define ChromiumWebBrowser in xaml or you instantiate it in code and set as the control's content? Only thing I can think of is the time of ChromiumWebBrowser instance creation but that shouldnt impact anything

Comment: If you are creating a ChromiumWebBrowser instance in xaml then binding to the Address dependency property is an option. The timing of code behind and xaml should yield the same result from a user point of view. Much of what happens internally to ChromiumWebBrowser is async, so there are a few different code paths depending on timing. The project is built with sourcelink so you can step directly into the code and add some breakpoints to get a better understanding of what's going on. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/improving-debug-time-productivity-with-source-link/#debugging-a-dependency

Comment: @amaitland sure, thanks. I get initial address from an event coming from another object. So it happens some time after the control itself has been initialized. The options I have is to either define ChromiumWebBrowser in xaml, then call LoadUrl in that event handler, OR completely instantiate ChromiumWebBrowser and set it as Content of the control and call LoadUrl, all in that event handler. Anyway I didnt yet observe any differences between these setups other than that in the second one I dont have initial focus on the browser

Comment: Use FocusManager to set the focus.

Comment: @amaitland I just call ChromiumWebBrowser's Focus() in IsBrowserInitializedChanged and it works perfectly

Comment: That'll work too. I did make some improvements a little while ago so the browser should correctly take focus say from the focus manager before it's been initialized. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/a48cf807e639d6a7180f5e773c69ef5466139abc#diff-b2b05731f147cdc4af2cf8c1fbb25e9e18f8b55082780092d52777dc2dccafc6R12

Comment: @amaitland I see, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting in version 95 it is no longer required to wait for the browser to initialize.

Calling LoadUrl immediately after instantiating a ChromiumWebBrowser instance in WPF will internally set the initial address which as the name implies is the url initially loaded in the browser.

So your code is fine as is.